# Calling function in C by its name and by function pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers

I want to know what is the difference between calling function by its name like

```
int sum(int x,int y)
 {
    return x+y;
 }

int main()
 { 
    int z = sum(5,7);
 }
```

and calling by pointer to function like

```
int sum(int x,int y)
 {
    return x+y; 
 }

int main()
 {  
    int (*ptr)(int,int);
    ptr =&sum;
    int z = (*ptr)(5,7); 
 }
```

is there any difference in execution time or anything?

Comment: The answer is: use a _profiler_ (e.g. [gprof](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/), also take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools#C_and_C.2B.2B))

Comment: Take a look at the generated assembler code...

Comment: You can also write your last example as `ptr = sum; int z = ptr(5,7);`.

Answer (score 6):

For the compiler, it is much easyer to optimize code that calls functions by name, because it is known at compile time what code calls which function.

With (non-const) function pointers on the other hand, it is difficult to know to which function the pointer points to, so the compiler may not be able to optimize (inline for example) function calls through function pointers.

Comment: Most relevant aspect in regard to performance. The extra fetch instructions are negligible

Answer (score 0):

The first one will be translated in assembly to a CALL with an inmediate argument. The second one will be translated to a CALL with a register or memory address as an argument (indirect call).

Now the performane of both approaches are determined by the ability of the target machine to support calling a subroutine with other than an inmediate argument.

For example, [the x86 instruction set](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html) allows a CALL instruction to have an inmediate argument, a register argument or a memory argument. For near calls, the three methods are available. For far calls, only inmediate and memory arguments are available. What this means is that usually, calling a function by a pointer will have a little penalty, as the address to call to must be loaded from memory before the actual call is made by using another instruction. An inmediate operand call must also load the address to call to from memory (in the instruction fetch stage) but it doesn't need a separate instruction to do this, so this is a bit (one or two cycles) faster.